# AWS lightsail + Cloudflare inbounding security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-lightsail

I pointed DNS to lightsail AWS ip, but I still get error 524, I saw a video  on [enter link description here][1]

I tried it but it only works for EC2, am I missing anything?
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZvEkWagoc0

Comment: Does you website work if you don't use DNS, just with IP address?

Comment: Yes, it works without , but when I try cloundflare, I get error 524

Comment: You would have to provide more details, how did you setup your CF exactly.

Comment: On CF, I added DNS A and pointed to lightsail instance

Comment: Do I need to make any configuration on AWS after adding A record on CF @Marcin

Comment: Don't think so. Also are you sure you are using your domain in http? https probably will not work.

Comment: I have tried for both http https,yet doesn't load - http://nairametrics.com

Is there a setup I am missing for http or https?

Answer (score 0):

I did `curl -i nairametrics.com` and this is the result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 03:03:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddcd0fa70148de3e620861c404ece852d1610852591; expires=Tue, 16-Feb-21 03:03:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.nairametrics.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Location: https://nairametrics.com/
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 07afe4ff280000df24f6854000000001
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=J%2BqqT71RtS4n86tBwXNSNsRn2%2BlFNBO7zgzAzXAFcUF02JfxC54cvggI2SZZ8Re17YbSrAbBT1NT%2Fl1K7%2BQkVkuUNoIm1IyowQMAcWTLhzYX"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 612cd7784a2fdf24-MEL

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://nairametrics.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

As you can see you are being **redirected to HTTPS**. So if your application is not setup to handle HTTPS, you will be timing out.

In the link you can get more info about light-scale and its HTTPS:

- [SSL/TLS certificates in Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-tls-ssl-certificates-in-lightsail-https)